# dpkg-buildpackage error: missing files (usr/include/*)

Tags: linux, debian, shared-libraries, dpkg

I am trying to build a dev package out of some **.so files** - i.e libraries.

```
dh_make -f ../ mylibs.tar.gz
```

then I choose

```
 -l
```

since I want a library package.

A debian folder is created which consists of among others the **controlfile** and the **install file**.

When I finally create the package with

```
dpkg-buildpackage
```

I get the following error message:

```
dh_install: mylibs-dev missing files (usr/include/*), aborting
```

I dont understand what is missing since the headers are copied to

```
usr/include
```

I have checked the directory and the headers are copied there. So why do I get this error message?

the install-file look like this:

```
 usr/lib/lib*.so.*
```

So - may the path to usr/include be missing here? I've tried with

```
usr/include/h.*
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 2):

The debian install files are most often used for source packages that produce several binary packages. In that case, `dh_auto_install` installs to the directory `debian/tmp/` and `dh_install` moves the files from there to each package. However, when there is a single package, `dh_auto_install` takes a shortcut and installs directly to `debian/package-name/`. In that case, you only need to list in the install file the files that `make install` missed (usually none). If you list the regular, installed files, `dh_install` will get confused because it is still looking for them in `debian/tmp/`.

It is possible to override either the directory where `dh_auto_install` installs, or the directory where `dh_install` is looking, but you probably don't need either.